# Meaning of "I have $1000 to start September."

Tags: grammar, american-english

"I have $1000 to start September." Does this mean I have that sum at the beginning of September.

Comment: Yes.  At the start of September, you have $1000.

Comment: It is a common construction, at least in American English, especially when you are recounting a long story in shorter segments. (e.g. Telling about how your cupcake stand expanded from 3 sales per week in August to a multi-million dollar business in December.  _I opened my doors in August with 2 cupcakes and $5.  They sold quickly, and with the profits, I was able to make and sell 300 the next week.  Growth continued, and I had $1000 in the bank to start September._)

Comment: Frankly, as native Br E, that sentence tells me nothing, colloquial or otherwise. I would have to guess at the meaning & probably get it wrong.

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting. It's definitely very common in AmE. I'm actually surprised that you can't infer the meaning even if the phrase is unfamiliar.

Comment: I was surprised that Am E natives got it immediately - it really does say nothing to me. I could *guess* it could mean I had a grand with which to survive the month, but it doesn't *say* that to me. It's the 'to start' which really throws the nut-tightening implement in the comprehension works.

Comment: @Tetsujin Does the explanation of the influence of "to start" in my answer (below) resonate with you? Do some parts of that explanation make sense in BrE and some not?

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree, though I think if it had been "to start September *with*" I would have been more likely to guess the meaning.

Answer (score 4):

In American English, the sentence means that on September 1, you will have $1000 in your possession. If today is September 1, then you have that money right now. If September is in the future, then the sentence describes a plan in which you will have that money on September 1.

The phrase “to start September” suggests that the $1000 relates to some activity that will occupy the whole month of September. For example, a very likely meaning is that you *won’t* be getting any more money until October. That is, “to start” suggests that you need to make this money last until September finishes. A less likely but conceivable meaning is that a certain money-making project is planned to occur during September, and $1000 is the “seed money” with which you are planned to start that project, which hopefully will grow into something more by the time September finishes.

The speaker could have avoided suggesting that the whole month of September is significant by saying “I will have $1000 on September 1.”

Answer (score 1):

More or less.  It's got a lot of small ambiguities to me without full context.

The sentence as presented doesn't have enough context to determine if the speaker is saying they currently have or will have $1,000.  There's also not enough context to say if they're speaking about early September, or if they're talking about beginning something else at some point in September.

For example:

1. "I have to get the new lemonade stand in the park operational before autumn, but they're not giving me much time or money to do it with.  I have $1000 to start September."
2. "I just took a new job, and they needed someone so badly they offered to give me a bonus if I begin early.  I took them up on the offer.  I have $1000 to start September."
3. "Our costs run $5000 a month, but we're running into trouble.  I have $1000 to start September."

More concretely:

1. "I have $1000 that I need to use to get the business started by September."
2. "I have been given $1000 to begin a new job in September."
3. "I will have $1000 available at the beginning of September."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The phrase means that you have $1000 at the beginning of September,  and that you will use that money to pay September expenses. It also strongly implies that you are expecting or hoping to get more money sometime in September, or at least that you don't think $1000 will see you all the way through September.

Comment: I agree with the first word of this answer, but the rest is entirely dependent on context.

Comment: I strongly agree with @Adam in which most of the answer is indeed contextually speculated. The sentence only has the meaning of the possession of currency at a specific time. The rest is quite leading.

Comment: @CaseyLeClair The sentence doesn't even imply the possession of the money at any specific time. It could mean "I have been given (already) a hiring bonus of $1000 because I agreed to start the job in September." (In British English, that would be written "I have $1000 to start in September.")

Comment: The verb have in this sentence does imply possession. That is literally what the word means in this context.

Comment: That I agree with. There technically is no instance implied.

Comment: @CaseyLeClair Sorry, I deleted my comment and decided to just write another answer.

Comment: In American English, if you want to say that you have money at a particular time, you would say, "at the start of September" or "at the beginning of September." If you say "to start September," you are implying that the money is being used in some ongoing context. It would not be idiomatic to use "to start September" if you what you meant was "at the beginning of September"--at least not in any dialect I'm aware of.

Comment: This answer pretty much mirrors my initial assumptions. I'm not so sure it implies that you'll either get more money or else run out, but it at least implies you have limited expenses and therefore need to budget wisely.